# What does !src means in html

Tags: html, rubymine

When I use autocompletion in my IDE it fills like this

```
  <script !src=""></script>
```

Even I removed that bang `!` it simply works. So what does it means? Does it have any purpose I should be beware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` or `Source` attribute is used to specify the URL (path) of the file or link. In the `<script !src=""></script>` you need to specify the JavaScript file to load. It will work without the `!` mark.

It is also used with `<img>`, `<audio>` and `<video>` HTML tags.

Example:

```
<script src="scrip.js"></script>
```

Specifically to your question, HTML does not have `!src` but only `src`.